# Analytic continuation of given power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Studying for Analysis qualifier, specifically complex analysis.

**Problem**: Find an analytic continuation for the function $$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k+1}}{3^k}$$ at the point $a = 3-4i$.

**My attempt**:

Rewrite series: $f(z) = \frac{3z}{3-z}, |z|>3$. Laurent Series Expansion.

Write: $F(z) = b_0 + b_1(z-a) + b_2(z-a)^2+\ldots$

Set equality using Identity theorem: $F^k(a) = f^k(a)$. Begin solving for $b_k$.

Is this the way to go, or is there a simpler path?

Comment: As you said, $f$ converges on the disk $\{z:\, |z| < 3\}$ to $f(z) = \frac{3z}{3 - z}$, which is analytic away from $z = 3$. That's the required analytic continuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have shown $f(z)=\frac{3z}{3-z}$, you can just plug in $z=a$; the function defined by that formula exists in an open set that intersects (and incidentally includes) the domain of definition of the power series and that point (the only point where it doesn't exist is $z=3$). That is the definition of an analytic continuation.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Something about the function at any point with $|z|=3$ was worrying me because the original geometric series does not converge under this condition (say z = -3i) . Also, does an analytic continuation require that it be a power series with positive exponents or can it simply be the Laurent's series with potentially negative powers? Either way, I think your response is correct. Thanks for the help.